# intellisense for Kendo UI Attributes in HTML5 tags

Tags: kendo-ui

How to get intellisense for KendoUI attributes in HTML 5 tags? I have referenced `kendo.all-vsdoc.js` in my HTML file but still not getting intellisense for KendoUI attributes.

For ex :

```
<section data-role="layout" data-id="default">
    <header data-role="header">
        <div data-role="navbar">My App</div>
    </header>

    <footer data-role="footer">
        <div data-role="tabstrip">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
</section>
```

intellisense not getting for attributes like `data-role`, `data-id`.

Comment: You should also specify what IDE you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you can't get intellisense for kendo-specific data attributes. The vsdoc file is for JavaScript.